# Need Example Code for apostrophe-modal in Apostrophe CMS 2.0

Tags: modal-dialog, apostrophe-cms

I've seen the documentation for apostrophe-modal, but does anyone have sample code to use apostrophe-modal in the real world?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the lead architect of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

There are many such examples in the Apostrophe source code itself.

One of the most accessible perhaps is the tag manager module:

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/tree/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-tags

The modal itself:

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-tags/public/js/manager-modal.js

And the index.js file and the files it requires, which set up supporting server-side routes and push the relevant frontend asset files:

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-tags/index.js

Hope this is helpful to you!

Comment: Not very helpful, stackoverflow answers should include actual workable example code, not simply links to more documentation.

Comment: I agree, these examples are a bit overwhelming and seems they're also all for editor modals. It would be really helpful to have a simple example of modals that show content to site users. Could always use bootstrap modals, but would prefer to be using something native when it's available.

Comment: Use of apostrophe modals for logged-out users is generally not recommended, unless you need to give them a lot of the apostrophe editing experience too. Those modals are for the admin interface. Bootstrap modals are a fine choice. We're moving to an even leaner js build for logged-out site visitors, see apostrophe-lean-frontend.